# Настройка прокси SOCKS4/5 на aiohttp Python

Tags: python, requests, proxy, aiohttp, socks5

не получается настроить прокси SOCKS4/5 на aiohttp.
Пробовал модуль aiohttp_socks ,но выдает ошибку:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'ProxyConnector' from partially initialized module 
 'aiohttp_socks' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

async def test(url,prox):
connector = ProxyConnector.from_url(f'socks5://{prox}', rdns=True)
async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector) as session:

```
      try:
        async with session.get(url, proxy= f'http://{prox}',timeout=TEST_TIMEOUT) as response:
            resp_json = await response.json()
            
      except Exception as ex:
          pass
      
      else:
          if resp_json:
                    async with aiofiles.open('r.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
                        await file.write(f'{prox} - работает\n')
```

Спрашивал у GPT но выдал тоже самое.
Если кто знает, помогите с решение или дайте намек где по подробнее почитать.
Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Покажите полный текст ошибки